# 32 bit compatibility library on 64 bit system

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, 64-bit

On a 64 bit system running a 64 bit OS if I want to run 32 bit programs Ubuntu provides a 32 bit compatibility library, ia32-libs. I guess other OSs will provide similar compatibility libraries.

I am curious to know What exactly the 32 bit compatibility library does to provide the compatibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really *do* anything - it just contains 32-bit implementations of the library functions you might want to call.  You need such a library so that the functions you want to call are in an appropriate instruction set and use the appropriate ABI, for example.

When you run a 32-bit process on a 64-bit system, the operating system puts the processor into a 32-bit mode before switching context to run your program.

Comment: My program could be linking many libraries. How is it possible for ia32-libs to provide a 32 bit version for all those libraries ? Or does it provide the 32 bit equivalent for a standard set of libraries and if my program uses a library that is not handled by ia32-libs I have to get the 32 bit version of that library myself ?

Comment: ia32-libs presumably provides only the system libraries (libc, libm, and some others).  If you want to link your program with other libraries, you'll have to take care of that yourself, as you suggest.